# SP16 - List calendar view - Disable drag and drop

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list-view, 2016, calendar

I was created **calendar view** for sharepoint list.

[image]

I want to **disable** drag on ListItems in view, because when i drag and drop item data is changing.

Comment: Please go through this answer https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/25359/40602

Comment: @yayati, thanks for the useful link and We hope to raise a flag for such duplicated questions, thanks again for your help  :) - @@Gochky I tried the answer in the duplicated link in SP 2016 and worked properly! so we close the quest

Comment: Ok! Best regards!